# to solve sql exception Cannot find either column "partinfo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "partinfo.query", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml

I use this pgm to get value from a column in xmlstring format named partinfo.which is one of the columns in table test.the partinfo column can be treated as another table containing many columns.and i want to read data from one of this column which is installed date in this case.but while executing i am getting a

> **sql exception:** Cannot find either column "partinfo" or the user-defined
>   function or aggregate "partinfo.query", or the name is ambiguous.how
>   can i solve this.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try {

               SqlConnection con = new 
                   SqlConnection("Data Source=NIP007\\SQLEXPRESS;
                        Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sa;Password=nest123@!");
                con.Open();


            string query =  "SELECT [partinfo].query('.//InstalledDate').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')FROM [test]";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
           // StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
           // string PartInfo=string.Empty;


            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string str5 =dr.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str5))
                {

                    textBox1.Text=str5;
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your XML column in Test? I am guessing it is not PartInfo.

Comment: Also since I guess this is a follow on from your previous question is it possible to have more than one PartInfo per DocumentElement in your XML?

Comment: it is PartInfo.ya.its related to that question.yes more than one PartInfo per Documentelement in XML is possible..But i cant recognise What is the cause of this exception.Plz tell me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly where your error lies because, your SQL should work ok ([Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d3f2/4)) and not return an error, although I am not sure the output is what you would want as it just concatenates all the installed dates in the XML as one long string:

As said in my previous answer if you have multiple Installed Dates per row, you will want to use CROSS APPLY TO get the installed dates as separate rows.

**[Demo SQL using CROSS APPLY](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d3f2/2)**

If you really want the dates concatenated to one string then I'd suggest using a string builder to do this:

```
try
{
    string query = @"SELECT  InstalledDate = x.value('InstalledDate[1]', 'DATETIME')
                    FROM    dbo.Test
                            CROSS APPLY PartInfo.nodes('/DocumentElement/PartInfo') p (x);";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NIP007\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sa;Password=nest123@!"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string str5 = dr.GetString(0);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str5))
                {
                    builder.Append(str5 + ",");
                }
            }
            textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

If this doesn't help can you post the DDL of your table Test and some sample data.

Thanks